# How to timeout with exit(0) from Bash

Tags: bash, travis-ci

I am trying to setup a travis script where we run our application to make sure it starts up fine. If it does then we can pass the build. Testing catches errors on start up. However, it is an api server and if I run the binary and it is successful it will just run indefinitely.

I tried using the following:

`timeout --preserve-status 20s <binary>`

But this just returns the exit code of the binary which is 143 when killed from a timeout.

`timeout 20s <binary>`

This returns exit 127 when successful.

Is there a script I could use that runs the binary fails if the binary errors on startup and if sucessful starting up say after 20 seconds exits with 0 to pass the travis build?

Comment: I think I have a work around. I can run it in the background sleep for 20 seconds, then test it with a curl GET. If the server started up successfully the it will work, if not then it will return non zero exit.

Comment: That actually sounds way better than what you proposed here

Comment: I totally agree. Going with that, but the answer is a perfect answer for the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case you want to:

- Return **Exit code 0**:

  - If command completed successfully (code 0).
  - OR if command did not complete yet (code 124), but that's OK too.
- Return **Exit code 1**:

  - If command had a failure before timeout reached.

Then try this:

```
timeout 10m some_command || ( [[ $? -eq 124 ]] && \
echo "WARNING: Timeout reached, but that's OK" )
```

Answer (score 9):

No need to use `sleep` you can change your command in the following way to force the return code at `0`:

```
(timeout 20s <binary>; exit 0)
```

Example:

```
(timeout 2s '/bin/sleep' 100; exit 0) #subshell creation                                                                                        
echo $?
0
```

vs

```
timeout 2s '/bin/sleep' 100
echo $?
124
```

Comment: This answers the question perfectly. However, for my use case I am going to stick with the curl because if it doesn't startup within the window then I am catching a failure to start. The curl will catch that if for some reason the wait doesn't give it enough time.

Comment: This also returns 0 if the process dies with failure immediately, such as with `(timeout 2s '/bin/false'; exit 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is using `|| true`

```
▶ timeout 5s sleep 50
▶ echo $?
124

▶ timeout 5s sleep 50 || true
▶ echo $?
0
```