# bash exit 0 on timeout, exit non-0 on failure

Tags: bash, shell, timeout

I want to run a script with the `timeout` command and exit `0` if the script runs with no problem or the timeout occurs. Otherwise, if the script exits with some `non-0` code, I want to preserve that.

My imaginary syntax would be that `timeout` implements something like `--exit` so I can write `timeout --exit 0 10s ping google.com`.

I have seen [this other answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50382603/how-to-timeout-with-exit0-from-bash), which says you can handle the exit code of `timeout` with an `or` condition, like `timeout 10s ping google.com || [[ $? -eq 143 ]]`. But that is hard coding the result of `timeout`, and if my script fails and throws a `143`, it will fail silently. I also don't want to *force* exit 0. If the script fails I want to know.

I am looking for an answer that preserves all failures (and non-failures) from the script, but always exits 0 from `timeout`. If there is a workaround that doesn't use `timeout` with a low cognitive complexity I will consider that as well.

Comment: The key is to read the man page carefully, most of the time it contains the information you are looking for - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html (reg. status 124)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the `timeout` command, and save its exit code to a variable. Compare that against 124, which is the code when the command times out. If the code was 124, we'll exit with 0 to convert the failing exit code into success. If the exit code was not 124, we have the original command's status because `timeout` exits with that when the command ran to completion.

```
timeout 10s COMMAND
status="$?"
if (( status == 124 )); then
    # Command timed out
    exit 0
fi
# Command either succeeded or failed
exit "$status"
```

The one gotcha is when the original command exits with 124 as `timeout` will propagate that exit code too. To this code, it will look like the command timed out so it will exit with 0 when it should be exiting with nonzero as the original command failed. There is no (easy) way to differentiate the two situations.